# Why only last element is printing while using function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

1. I need to get the value for business' name and append it to a list.
2. I need to get the value policies and append to a list after checking parent.
3. if parent is Marketing name has to added to level1.
4. if parent is Advertising name has to added to level2.
5. if some place Business is `[]` I need to pass `None` instead of Null List
6. Also need to check key exists or not for some keys there is a chance of missing policies, business
   dictionary is below
7. If in the list contains same elements example `'Business':['Customer', Customer]` then only one element has to take

```
searchtest = [
    {'_index': 'newtest',
    '_type': '_doc',
    '_id': '100',
    '_score': 1.0,
    '_source': {'id': '100',
                'name': 'A',
                'policies': [
                    {
                    'id': '332',
                    'name': 'Second division',
                    'parent': 'Marketing'},
                    {'id': '3323', 'name': 
                     'First division', 
                     'parent':  'Marketing'}
                ]
            }
        },
        {'_index': 'newtest',
         '_type': '_doc',
         '_id': '101',
         '_score': 1.0,
         '_source': {
            'id': '101',
            'name': 'B',
            'Business': [{'id': '9'}, {'id': '10', 'name': 'Customer'}],
            'policies': [{'id': '332', 'name': 'Second division', 'parent': 'Marketing'}, {'id': '3323', 'name': 'First division', 'parent': 'Advertising'}]}}]`
```

Code is below

```
def business(searchtest):
    for el in searchtest:
        Business_List = []
        if 'Business' in el['_source']:
            for j in el['_source']['Business']:
                 if 'name' in j:
                    Business_List.append(j['name'])
        else:
            Business_List.extend([])
    return Business_List
            
def policy(searchtest):
    for el in searchtest:
        level1= []
        if 'policies' in  el['_source']:
            for j in el['_source']['policies']:
                 if 'parent' in j:
                        if 'Marketing' in j['parent']  :
                            level1.append(j['name'])
        else:
            level1.extend([])

        level2= []
        if 'policies' in  el['_source']:
            for j in el['_source']['policies']:
                 if 'parent' in j:
                        if 'Advertising' in j['parent']:
                            level2.append(j['name'])
        else:
            level2.extend([])
    return [level1, level2]

def data_product(searchtest):
    resp = []
    for el in searchtest:
        d = {
                'id'       : el['_source']['id'],
                'name'     : el['_source']['name'],
                'Business' : business(searchtest),

                'level1'    : policy(searchtest)[0],
                'level2'   : policy(searchtest)[1]


            }

    resp.append(d)
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(data_product(searchtest))
```

My output

```
[   {   'Business': [],
        'id': '101',
        'level1': ['Second division'],
        'level2': ['First division'],
        'name': 'B'}]
```

Expected out

```
[  {   'Business': [],
        'id': '100',
        'level1': ['Second division','First division'],
        'level2': [],
        'name': 'A'},
 {   'Business': ['Customer'],
        'id': '101',
        'level1': ['Second division'],
        'level2': ['First division'],
        'name': 'B'}]
```

if `resp.append(d)` is put inside the loop then only one id is repeating?

Comment: I didn't get where `do_the_thing` definition? If you show us a mocked source, provide us the worked example with the unexpected result to try and debug it locally.

Comment: @kirill.z sorry i haved edited the code. that was testing one

Comment: `resp.append(d)` should be in the loop. Add a level of indentation.

Comment: @Barmar i tried but now first id is repeating 2 times??

Comment: `business(searchtest)` will return the same result each time through the loop, since it doesn't depend on `el`.

Comment: @Barmar  that also i have intend it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my whole code with change

```
searchtest = [{'_index': 'newtest',
               '_type': '_doc',
               '_id': '100',
               '_score': 1.0,
               '_source': {'id': '100',
                           'name': 'A',
                           'policies': [{'id': '332',
                                         'name': 'Second division',
                                         'parent': 'Marketing'},
                                        {'id': '3323', 'name': 'First division', 'parent': 'Marketing'}]}},
              {'_index': 'newtest',
               '_type': '_doc',
               '_id': '101',
               '_score': 1.0,
               '_source': {'id': '101',
                           'name': 'B',
                           'Business': [{'id': '9'}, {'id': '10', 'name': 'Customer'}],
                           'policies': [{'id': '332',
                                         'name': 'Second division',
                                         'parent': 'Marketing'},
                                        {'id': '3323', 'name': 'First division', 'parent': 'Advertising'}]}}]


def business(el):
    Business_List = []
    # for el in searchtest:
    if 'Business' in el['_source']:
        for j in el['_source']['Business']:
            if 'name' in j:
                Business_List.append(j['name'])
    else:
        Business_List.extend([])
    return Business_List


def policy(searchtest):
    for el in searchtest:
        level1 = []
        if 'policies' in el['_source']:
            for j in el['_source']['policies']:
                if 'parent' in j:
                    if 'Marketing' in j['parent']:
                        level1 .append(j['name'])
        else:
            level1 .extend([])

        level2 = []
        if 'policies' in el['_source']:
            for j in el['_source']['policies']:
                if 'parent' in j:
                    if 'Advertising' in j['parent']:
                        level2.append(j['name'])
        else:
            level2.extend([])
    return [level1, level1 ]


def data_product(searchtest):
    resp = []
    for el in searchtest:
        d = {
            'id': el['_source']['id'],
            'name': el['_source']['name'],
            'Business': business(el),

            'level1': policy(searchtest)[0],
            'level2': policy(searchtest)[1]

        }

        resp.append(d)
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pprint

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(4)
    pp.pprint(data_product(searchtest))
```

output:

```
 [   {   'Business': [],
        'id': '100',
        'level1': ['Second division'],
        'level2': ['First division'],
        'name': 'A'},
    {   'Business': ['Customer'],
        'id': '101',
        'level1': ['Second division'],
        'level2': ['First division'],
        'name': 'B'}]
```

Comment: please read last sentence of the question

Comment: @aysh plz check the code now it is giving the expected result